# Workflow to send reminder email to owner and manager when invoice is overdue?

Tags: workflow, email-alert

I have a custom object, Sales Invoice, that has a custom formula field to calculate the number of days overdue.  I want to send an automated email at XX days overdue to both the account owner and their manager.

My first problem is I don't think the workflow is going.  I have it set to send an email alert when Days_Overdue__c = XX (formula is TODAY()-Due_Date__c) criteria is everytime created and edited to meet criteria.  I also have two time based workflows that updates a picklist with either 1 or 2, switching off each day (if value =1, update picklist value to 2 in 24 hours and the opposite if value=2).  I was thinking this would take care of needing to edit the record for the email workflow to send.  If I manually edit a record, the email workflow works properly.

My second problem is the manager's email.  I created an email field on the object which has another workflow to update to the contents to Account__r.Owner.Manager.Email when Sales Invoice: Manager's Email NOT EQUAL TO Account__r.Owner.Manager.Email.  The manager email does populate when the record is created, but not if the account owner changes or on records that existed before this was created(which I thought would also be updated with the picklist 1/2 workflows).

Am I making this too complicated?

Comment: are you using formula field to trigger your workflow?

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating a timed based workflow rule which would run 2 days after the Due_Date. Have it update the email field and then send the email. According to this doc [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_rules_considerations.htm&language=en) you cannot predict the order the actions will occur but field updates will be executed first:

> The order in which individual actions and types of actions are
>   executed is not guaranteed. However, field update actions are executed
>   first, followed by other actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating time based workflow action on due date.
here is the link to understand https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US